# Power Query - IF Statement referencing another table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I would like to add a YES/NO column using an `IF` statement within Power Query on Power BI referencing another table. Below is what I would like to achieve:

Thanks in advance

```
if [id] = table2[id] and [group] = table2[group] and [start_time] >= table2[start_time] and [start_time] <= table2[end_time] then "yes" else "no"
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you share what you've tried so far and the issues you encountered while doing it?

Comment: I added a Custom Column in Power Query and I can't add the table2 data to the formula based on what I entered in the code I shared. Maybe there is another way of finding the data from another table and adding it to the formula?

Comment: As an alternative you could add it as a calculated column after loading in to the data model. DAX definitely has the capacity to do this.